# Advice: subforms in a form

Tags: form

I would like to have some guidance for my approach:

I want to create a form and for some sections of the form, have a functinoality which allows you to add additional information. For example.

1. Section 1
2. Section 2 (Requirements)
         2a. Requirement 1 (given default fields)
         *Click here to add another requirement* (this will prompt same fields as for Requirement 1)

Any advice would be great! Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you to use infopath and use repeating table or section depending on your requirement.http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/infopath-help/insert-a-repeating-section-HP010080915.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Infopath is still supported by Microsoft but not being updated and wont have another version. Microsoft has promised us there will be an upgrade path to whatever is next.  However - it's been a year since that announcement but we have not seen anything come out of Redmond.  My advice is stay away from InfoPath path.

You didn't indicate your platform - but MS is pushing more towards using Access Apps for custom forms in O365.  You can do this on premise too if it's configured.

Another option only available in O365 is using Excel Forms.  This has not yet made it's way to on-premise office web apps servers.  I'm light on these so not sure if they can handle your conditional logic, it's something you would need to explore.

Moving away from that you can build a custom form with SharePoint designer or Visual Studio and use .NET controls and a little code for creating your conditional elements.  You also have the option of just creating an HTML form with JavaScript. This has been a popular option creating a page and using JQeury and SPServices to create cascading dropdowns and sections.